# Max of elements of a family of countable functions

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, continuity, maxima-minima

Let $\left\{ \omega_k \right\}_{k \geq 0}$ a sequence of not decreasing value such that

$$
\omega_k \leq \sum_{j\geq k+1} \omega_j
$$

Let $t \in A = \left[-\sum_{j\geq 0}\omega_j, \sum_{j\geq 0}\omega_j \right]$ and $t_k$ defined as

\begin{equation}
t_{k} = \left\{
\begin{array}{ll}
0 & k = 0 \\
t_{k-1} + d_{k-1}(t)\omega_{k-1} & k \geq 1
\end{array}
\right.
\end{equation}
where 
$$
d_k(t) = \left\{
\begin{array}{rl}
1 & t \geq t_k \\
-1 & t < t_k
\end{array}
\right.
$$
It can be proved by induction that
$$
-\sum_{j\geq k}\omega_k \leq t - t_k  \leq \sum_{j\geq k} \omega_k.
$$

For all natural $k \geq 0$ let $f_{k}(t)$ defined in $A$ as
\begin{equation}
f_k(t) = t - t_k
\end{equation}
And let's consider the family of functions
\begin{equation}
\mathcal{F} = \left\{ f_k \right\}_{k\geq0}
\end{equation}
I want prove/disprove that for all $f_k \in \mathcal{F}$ $f_k$ has a maximum/minimum value, given the property of the difference $f_k(t) = t - t_k$ we know it is bounded, and by the least upper bound we have that $f_k$ has supremum/infimum. By induction I was trying to prove that $f_k$ has such property. For $k = 0$ we have
$$
f_0(t) = t
$$
which is the identity function, but defined in a bounded interval, so it is bounded. Assuming until $k$ the property holds I was studying the case $k+1$, we have that

$$
f_{k+1}(t) = f_{k}(t) - d_k(t) \omega_k
$$

But I'm stuck here, I was trying to use $\hat{t}$ as argmax/argmin of $f_k$, however such value doesn't guarantee that $f_{k+1}$ achieve the max/min for the same value.

Update:

The other clue I'm having right now is the following. We clearly have

$$
f_k(t) = t - \sum_{0 \leq j \leq k-1} d_j(t) \omega_j = t - <D_{k-1}(t),\Omega_{k-1}>
$$
where
$$
\begin{array}{l}
D_{k-1}(t) = \left(d_0(t),\ldots,d_{k-1}(t) \right) \\
\Omega_{k-1} = \left(\omega_0,\ldots,\omega_{k-1} \right)
\end{array}
$$

For all $k$ I can then write $A$ as finite union of disjoint set $\left\{A_j\right\}_{j \in J}$ where each $A_j$ is defined as

$$
A_j = 
\left\{ t \in A : D_{k-1}(t) = \text{constant}_j \right\}
$$

So we would have that
$$
\max_{t \in A} \left\{ f_k(t) \right\} = 
\max_{j \in J} \left\{ \max_{t \in A_j} \left\{ f_k(t) \right\} \right\}
$$

Given that for all $j \in J$ the restriction $f_k |_{A_j}$ is continuous and defined in a bounded interval we have that that $f_k$ has maximum, $J$ is finite, so the max of all the max exists as well.

Not too much rigorous, but that's probably the way to go.